# Stack template - pop function returns address and not value

Tags: c++, templates, stack

I'm trying to create a Stack using templates in C++, everything works fine exepct for the Pop function, that returns the item's address and not actual value, the code is below.

```
 template <typename T>
 class Stack {

const int size;
T* data;
int index;

public:
    Stack(){};
    Stack (const int S);
    ~Stack(){delete [] data;};
    bool Push (const T& info);
    T Pop ();
    bool is_empty();
};

 template <typename T>
 Stack <T> ::Stack (const int S) : size(S)  // Stack CTOR
 {
  this->data = new T [this->size];
  this->index=0;
 }

 template <typename T>
 bool Stack<T> ::Push (const T& info)
 {  

  if(index==(size-1))
            return false;
   else{
      this->data[index] = info;
      index++;
      return true;}
 }


template <typename T>
T Stack <T> ::Pop ()
{       
    index--;
    return (this->data[index+1]);
} 

 template <typename T>
 bool Stack<T> ::is_empty()
 {
  if(index==0){return true;}
        else
            return false;
  }
```

And the main() is:

```
Stack <int> Sint (10);
Sint.Push(6);
int X = Sint.Pop();
cout<<X;  // prints out the address and not the value
```

thanks in advance !

Comment: Where is `data` initialized?  In C and C++ dynamic arrays need a location in memory to hold their stuff.  You have only declared a pointer.  You delete the allocated memory, but I don't see where you allocated memory for the array.

Comment: I suggest getting out of the habit of `this->` and referencing the item directly.  Less typing, less chance of mistakes and not using pointers.

Comment: there is a CTOR for it, it's not here.

Comment: @DavidFaiz: Then you'll have to show it I guess

Comment: @Thomas : `this->` isn't a bad idea in class templates due to [two-phase name lookup](http://blog.llvm.org/2009/12/dreaded-two-phase-name-lookup.html).

Comment: Aside: pop shouldn't generally return anything (you normally want something like `top` to return top item, pop just remove item).

Comment: @JerryCoffin i know, i use like that just for this issue, i expect the same problem with a Top function in my case.

I've added the CTOR & All relevant libraries are included

Comment: @DavidFaiz: Give us `Push()` as well :)

Comment: Added entire code guys

Comment: The point of having `top()` separated from `pop()` is that `top()` can return a const reference to the top element. Just make sure that `pop()` is never run if there are still references to the top element anywehere in the code.

Comment: @AxelOmega took your advice and gave the function Pop standard Top syntex and works great !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
 template <typename T>
 bool Stack<T> ::Push (const T& info)
 {
     if (index == (size-1))
     {
         return false;
     }
     else
     {    
         this->data[index] = info;
         index++; // index becomes 1 after the first insertion...
         return true;
     }
 }
```

If the stack is empty, you store the item at index 0 an increase the index, which becomes 1. Then here:

```
template <typename T>
T Stack <T> ::Pop ()
{
    index--; // index becomes 0...
    return (this->data[index+1]); // returning the uninitialized item at
                                  // index 0 + 1 = 1...
}
```

You are decreasing the index, which becomes 0, and then returning the item at index 1, which was never assigned. What you see printed is not the address of the first element, but the value of the uninitialized second element.

What you should do is:

```
template <typename T>
T Stack <T> ::Pop ()
{
    if (index == 0)
    {
        // Maybe throw an exception?
        // You should handle the error condition somehow.
        return T();
    }
    else
    {
        index--;
        return (this->data[index]);
    }
}
```